# convert GMT 0:00 to GMT +5:30 sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

when i stored my user_login_date into database it was GMT +5:30 but my database is set to GMT 0:00

example when user logged in at 12:00:00 but database stored that date as 07:30:00

now what to do if i want to fetch this data as GMT +5:30 Timezone

Comment: Refer [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/930900/6327676)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the DATE_ADD hre as below:

```
select date_add(date_add(your_column, interval 5 hour),interval 30 minute);
```

Or you can simply use:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(your_column,'+00:00','+05:30')
```